# How to run a specific unit test in a test script in brownie?

Tags: solidity, brownie, unittesting

Say I have a python test script in my brownie project's `/tests` directory with a number of difference test cases, is it possible to pass a flag to only execute a certain test function in brownie?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run a specific test with the brownie command.

**Example:**

```
brownie test tests/Example_test.py
```

Would also advise using `--coverage` to see the coverage of your smart-contract.

```
brownie test tests/Example_test.py --coverage
```

Answer (score 0):

Since brownie uses [pytest](https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/#testing), you can run the tests directly with `pytest` and this allows you to [specify the tests](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html#specifying-which-tests-to-run) you would like to run.

For example,

```
pytest tests/test_contract_abc.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```shell
brownie test tests/test_contract_abc.py::specific_test_function_name
```

Here's an answer about pytest - you can start the command with `brownie test` instead of `pytest` or `python -m pytest` and keep all the flags and arguments the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493489/408165